# SciPy method eigsh giving nonintuitive results

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I tried to use SciPy function `linalg.eigsh` to calculate a few eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix. However, when I print the calculated eigenvectors, they are of the same dimension as the number of eigenvalues I wanted to calculate. Shouldn't it give me the actual eigenvector, whose dimension is the same as that of the original matrix?

My code for reference:

```
id = np.eye(13)
val, vec = sp.sparse.linalg.eigsh(id, k = 2)
print(vec[1])
```

Which gives me:

```
[-0.26158945  0.63952164]
```

While intuitively it should have a dimension of 13. And it should not be a non-integer value either. Is it just my misinterpretation of the function? If so, is there any other function in Python that can calculate a few eigenvectors (I don't want the full spectrum) of the wanted dimensionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vec` is an array with shape (13, 2).

```
In [21]: vec
Out[21]: 
array([[ 0.36312724, -0.04921923],
       [-0.26158945,  0.63952164],
       [ 0.41693924,  0.34811192],
       [ 0.30068329, -0.11360339],
       [-0.05388733, -0.3225355 ],
       [ 0.47402124, -0.28180261],
       [ 0.50581823,  0.29527393],
       [ 0.06687073,  0.19762049],
       [ 0.103382  ,  0.29724875],
       [-0.09819873,  0.00949533],
       [ 0.05458907, -0.22466131],
       [ 0.15499849,  0.0621803 ],
       [ 0.01420219,  0.04509334]])
```

The eigenvectors are stored in the *columns* of vec.  To see the first eigenvector, use `vec[:, 0]`.  When you printed `vec[0]` (which is equivalent to `vec[0, :]`), you printed the first row of `vec`, which is just the first components of the two eigenvectors.

Comment: While it makes physical sense, functionally storing the eigenvectors in a single array would be most intuitive, one would think. Thanks for the insight!